# Deadlock when dropping child partition tables

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning, database-deadlocks

We have a database that contains statistical data. The tables are partitioned
using inheritance according to time. New child tables are created as needed
according to incoming data, and the application runs a nightly job that
drops old child tables.

To maintain consistency, all child tables that are associated with a single time 
period are dropped inside a single transaction.

We find we are now getting deadlocks between the DROP sequence and normal
SELECT queries. The (vastly simplified) example below illustrates the
problem:

1. DDL & insert a dummy row

   ```
   CREATE TABLE a(id serial primary key, t timestamp with time zone, i int);
   CREATE TABLE a1 () inherits (a);
   CREATE TABLE a2 () inherits (a);
   CREATE TABLE b(id serial primary key, id_a int, x int, y int);
   CREATE TABLE b1 () inherits (b);
   CREATE TABLE b2 () inherits (b);

   INSERT INTO a1(t,i) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 100);
   INSERT INTO b1(id_a,x,y) VALUES (1,200,300);
   ```
2. In one psql session, run the following (simulating a long running query):

   ```
   SELECT pg_sleep(90) 
   FROM b
   LEFT JOIN a on a.id=b.id_a;
   ```
3. In a second psql session, run the following:

   ```
   BEGIN;
   DROP TABLE a2;
   DROP TABLE b2;
   ```
4. In a third session, run this (same query as in the first session):

   ```
   SELECT pg_sleep(90) 
   FROM b
   LEFT JOIN a on a.id=b.id_a;
   ```

When the query started in step 2 completes or is interrupted, a deadlock occurs.

```
DETAIL:  Process 19894 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 129716 of database 44449; blocked by process 20017.
Process 20017 waits for AccessShareLock on relation 129700 of database 44449; blocked by process 19894.
```

The problem is easy to spot: The locks taken by the DROP transaction are in order of a2 then b2, but the locks are taken in the opposite order by the SELECT
statements. It seems like the SELECT statements take their locks in order of
the joins in the query.

We have tried locking the tables using a single LOCK command before dropping them: that did not help, they are locked in the order they are listed in the LOCK command and the deadlock still occurs if that is not the same as the order they appear in all SELECT queries.

We don't want to have to enforce a particular join order for all user queries just to ensure that we don't get deadlocks when expiring old data.

For one thing we have found that depending on the SELECT query we are trying to perform we get much worse performance using one join order compared to another (I know the this should not be, but the planner picks a better plan when we use one join order compared to another).

For another thing, the queries are generated dynamically depending on user input
and enforcing a join order across the board would limit the queries that can
be performed (the real life queries are much more complex and can involve a lot
of tables, views, subqueries, etc).

A I correct in assuming the join order is determining the order in which the locks are taken for a SELECT query?

Is there any way to avoid these deadlocks without enforcing a specific join
order on read-only SELECT queries?

We are using Postgresql 9.6.6.

Answer (score 0):

The order in which tables are processed is not necessarily the order in which they appear in the query. But that join order is determined during planning, and during planning, the tables will first be processed (and locked) in the order in which they appear in the query.

You say that all the tables you want to drop are inheritance children, so I am surprised that your queries access the partitions directly rather than the parent table. If all queries access the parent tables, you should be able to avoid deadlocks by locking the parent table in `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` mode before dropping any of the inheritance children.

Comment: Thanks. We do query at the parent tables (tables a, b in the example above). I tried `LOCK TABLE a,b IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;` before dropping  any tables, but it does not help, you still get a deadlock.

Comment: Lock only one parent table per transaction, that is, use multiple transactions to drop partitions in multiple tables.

Comment: As stated in the question - we want to do it in a single transaction to ensure that either all related child tables are dropped, or none are. We could add more application level code to ensure integrity, but I was hoping that would not be necessary

Comment: With that requirement, a deadlock seems unavoidable. Perhaps you could suspend all concurrent activity during that time.